# Setting popup box with osascript and a 10 second delay

Tags: bash, osascript

I'm looking to setup a popup box for users to see that has a 10 second delay before it exits and the script continues. So far I've got the following.

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog with delay "10" "Running Health Check \r \rPlease allow 30 seconds or more to complete." with title "Health Check"'
```

I've read that you can use the "delay" function, but I'm having problems getting it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, what I needed to do was add in the following...

```
giving up after 10
```

So my overall script now looks like this...

```
osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to display dialog with delay "10" "Running Health Check \r \rPlease allow 30 seconds or more to complete." giving up after 10 with title "Health Check"'
```